# How to download a file in PyCharm instead of !wget in Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When I try some codes in pandas, the bash code wget is used in colab as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

!wget abc.com/sales.csv
```

If I want to use PyCharm to download the above internet file, wget is not recognized.
So which command should I use to download this file?

Comment: maybe you can give this a shot? https://pypi.org/project/wget/

Comment: I found that wget is a package and I needed to install it in PyCharm, then to use it on top of your recommended url. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did u get it working?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot for Regressor's hints!
Here is what I test to be successful to share in case anyone meets this issue:

(1) install wget in package in PyCharm

File->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter->+->Input: wget->Install Package

(2) Run the following command

```
import wget
url = 'abc.com/sales.csv'
filename = wget.download(url)
print(filename)
```